# Data is lost somewhere in action wiring

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, firebase-authentication, redux-async-actions

I have a simple registration form with fields for email, password, and admin code. I am passing this data into my action creator and I have it passing through three actions before finishing up the registration. Somewhere in there, it is just stopping. It returns no errors. Here is my code.

```
export const checkAdminCode = ({ email, password, adminCode }, history) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: CHECK_ADMIN_CODE });

    firebase.database().ref('/env/adminCode').once('value', (snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.val() === adminCode) {
        return registerUser(email, password, history, dispatch);
      }

      return loginUserFail(dispatch);
    });
  };
};

const registerUser = (email, password, history, dispatch) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: REGISTER_USER });

    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((user) => loginUserSuccess(dispatch, history, user))
      .catch((err) => loginUserFail(dispatch, err));      
  };
};

const loginUserSuccess = (dispatch, history, user) => {
  history.push('/admin/dashboard');
  dispatch({
    type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
    paylaod: user
  });
};
```

A few things to note:

- `if (snapshot.val() === adminCode) {` does work.
- Before I added the admin code, I had the form submit fire straight to `registerUser`and it worked.
- I placed a few console.logs to try to find exactly where the breakdown was happening. Upon testing the following code:

  ```
  const registerUser = (email, password, history, dispatch) => {
    console.log('test1');
    return (dispatch) => {
      console.log('test2');
      dispatch({ type: REGISTER_USER });

      firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((user) => loginUserSuccess(dispatch, history, user))
        .catch((err) => loginUserFail(dispatch, err));      
    };
  };
  ```

`console.log('test1');` worked, `console.log('test2');` didn't work.

Once again, it's returning no error, so I don't know how else to describe what's going on or what to search.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi! Usually this type of errors are easily sorted out with help of a debugger, You could just set breakpoints in all critical points of your code and see how the flow goes..

Comment: Also, I'm not quite familiar with thunk (prefer to write middleware instead), but shouldn't this line `return registerUser(email, password, history, dispatch);` be more like `dispatch({ type: 'REGISTER_USER, payload: { email, password, history  } })` ? It seems a bit strange to see dispatch as an argument of action creators. Also, btw, there is no need to pass history to actions creators, because dispatch router actions as well (react-redux-router), otherwise they become to smart, action creators I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`registerUser` is [`async redux action`](https://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html),you need to call it with `dispatch`.

You don't need to pass `dispatch` explicitaly to invoking function.

It will passed implicitely by redux.

```
export const checkAdminCode = ({ email, password, adminCode }, history) => {
      return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({ type: CHECK_ADMIN_CODE });

        firebase.database().ref('/env/adminCode').once('value', (snapshot) => {
          if (snapshot.val() === adminCode) {

            dispatch (registerUser(email, password, history));
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

          }

          return loginUserFail(dispatch);
        });
      };
    };
```